# How to unmarshal an XML String contain diffgr to JAVA POJO

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Hi I got a below XML string which contain diffgram

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Result xmlns="">
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <DT1 diffgr:id="DT11" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <TEST_NO>93481324345</TEST_NO>
                <TEST_DESC>Description1</TEST_DESC>
            </DT1>
            <DT1 diffgr:id="DT12" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                <TEST_NO>93481366454</TEST_NO>
                <TEST_DESC>Description2</TEST_DESC>
            </DT1>
            <DT1 diffgr:id="DT13" msdata:rowOrder="2">
                <TEST_NO>934813267783</TEST_NO>
                <TEST_DESC>Description3</TEST_DESC>
            </DT1>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</Result>
```

How can I unmarshal this String to java POJO using JAXB ?

Below are the current POJO seems not able to bind by this way.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "diffgr",
    "newDataSet",
    "dt"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="Result")
public class Response {
    
    @XmlElement(name = "diffgr:diffgram")
    protected String diffgr;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "NewDataSet")
    protected String newDataSet;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "DT1")
    protected List<Response.DT> dt;

    public String getDiffgr() {
        return diffgr;
    }

    public void setDiffgr(String diffgr) {
        this.diffgr = diffgr;
    }


    public String getNewDataSet() {
        return newDataSet;
    }


    public void setNewDataSet(String newDataSet) {
        this.newDataSet = newDataSet;
    }


    public List<Response.DT> getDt() {
        if (dt == null) {
            dt = new ArrayList<Response.DT>();
        }
        return this.dt;
    }


    public void setDt(List<Response.DT> dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response [diffgr=" + diffgr + ", newDataSet=" + newDataSet + ", dt=" + dt + "]";
    }



    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "testNo",
        "testDesc"
    })
    public static class DT {

        @XmlElement(name = "TEST_NO")
        protected String testNo;
        @XmlElement(name = "TEST_DESC")
        protected String testDesc;
        
        public String getTestNo() {
            return testNo;
        }

        public void setTestNo(String testNo) {
            this.testNo = testNo;
        }
        
        public String getTestDesc() {
            return testDesc;
        }

        public void setTestDesc(String testDesc) {
            this.testDesc = testDesc;
        }
        
        

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DT [testNo=" + testNo + ", testDesc=" + testDesc + "]";
        }
        
        
        


    }
    

}
```

I'm using the below sample code to unmarshal the String

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnMarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Response response = (Response)jaxbUnMarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
```

When execute there is no any error throwing out while the POJO was empty.

How to unmarshal an XML String contain diffgr to JAVA POJO like this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse XML document with elements like <g:id> using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905771/parse-xml-document-with-elements-like-gid-using-jaxb)

Comment: Another reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234091/how-to-unmarshall-xml-code-containing-diffgr